# Mastermind Python with String.split()

Tags: python

How can you make this program make the user input 5 digits at once, instead of asking separate numbers each time? I know I have to use string.split() but where would I place the code and execute the code.

```
Heading

from random import randint

n1 = randint(1,9)
n2 = randint(1,9)
n3 = randint(1,9)
n4 = randint(1,9)
c = 1

while True:
    print (n1,n2,n3,n4)
    guess1 = input("guess the first number")
    guess2 = input("guess the second number")
    guess3 = input("guess the third number")
    guess4 = input("guess the fourth number")
    guess1 = int(guess1)
    guess2 = int(guess2)
    guess3 = int(guess3)
    guess4 = int(guess4)
    numberswrong = 0

    if guess1 != n1:
        numberswrong += 1
    if guess2 != n2:
        numberswrong += 1

    if guess3 != n3:
        numberswrong += 1

    if guess4 != n4:
        numberswrong += 1

    if numberswrong == 0:
        print('Well Done!')
        print('It took you ' + str(c) + ' ries to guess the number!')
        break
    else:
        print('You got ' + str(4-numberswrong) + ' numbers right.')
    c += 1
```

Comment: If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox as it also helps and motivates the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to split the numbers in a single input and convert them into integers using a list comprehension. You can also create your `random_n` using a similar method.

```
from random import randint

random_n = [randint(1,9) for i in range(4)]
c = 1

while True:
    print(random_n)
    user_input = [int(i) for i in input("guess the numbers: ").split()]

    numberswrong = 0

    if user_input[0] != random_n[0]:
        numberswrong += 1
    if user_input[1] != random_n[1]:
        numberswrong += 1
    if user_input[2] != random_n[2]:
        numberswrong += 1
    if user_input[3] != random_n[3]:
        numberswrong += 1

    if numberswrong == 0:
        print('Well Done!')
        print('It took you ' + str(c) + ' tries to guess the number!')
        break
    else:
        print('You got ' + str(4-numberswrong) + ' numbers right.')

    c += 1

    if c > 10:
        print('More than 10 failed attempts. End.')
        break

>>
[3, 9, 1, 6]
guess the numbers: 1 2 1 6
You got 2 numbers right.
[3, 9, 1, 6]
guess the numbers: 3 9 1 6
Well Done!
It took you 2 tries to guess the number!
```

**Edited:** Added break if attempts more than 10, in this case when your counter `c` is more than 10.

Comment: Also how can you limit the guesses to only 10? Also not having any duplicate numbers in the game?

Comment: You got your numbers wrong as a counter, and you know how to break. That should do it!

Comment: Is it possible to output that as a code and paste it here? Thank You

Comment: Updated to check your counter `c` value. Please also update your question to reflect the whole question including limiting to 10 attempts.

Comment: When I run the program, I keep getting this: user_input [int(i) for I in input(“Guess the numbers: ”).split()                AttributeError: ‘truple’ object has no attribute ‘split’

Comment: Can you post the proper traceback, it should not be `'truple'` and should not be `I`.

Comment: I need help with this: How do you display each turn, the user must be notified of how many turns remain. Also the program should ask the user if they would like to play again, this should be a yes or no question, and any invalid should cause the question to be repeated.

Comment: @Madara I suggest that you do some reading on flow controls, it will probably be more beneficial than me giving a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `raw_input`:

```
Guesses= raw_input("Guess 5 numbers (separated by comma)")
Guess_list= Guesses.split(",")
```

Comment: `raw_input` has been replaced with just input in Python 3.x, though it was not clearly stated, `print` as a function usually tells you that the user is on Python 3.x. Also, it would help OP if you post how your solution will work with the rest of the code if possible.